# How to translate "ripple move" into Portuguese?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Ripple move: *Oftentimes during editing, you need to move all the clips on a track at once. A quick way to do this is to use a ripple move. Hold shift, then click and drag a clip on the timeline.*

Another example: *You can also use ripple move to move multiple clips at the same time to any specific place in the timeline.*

For reference, please see [this tutorial on using ripple move](https://www.techsmith.com/tutorial-camtasia-ripple-move.html).

I've been thinking and would consider:

"movimento em ondulação?"

[image: tr]

Answer (score 4):

In electronics we have the Ripple Voltage, that is translated as "Ondulação residual" in portuguese, although it's more common to use the untranslated name. Based on that, and that the most common translation for 'ripple' is indeed 'ondulação', I assume that there's no literal translations for "ripple" in portuguese, but approximations. My guess then would be that your translation is good enough, but it would make more sense as "movimento em ondulação".

Answer (score 3):

Another possible direct translation for "ripple move" is

- *movimento ondulado*,

which happens to also be Google translator's suggestion.

But Adobe Premiere Pro's User Guide in Portuguese ([Guia do Usuário](https://helpx.adobe.com/br/premiere-pro/using/trimming-clips1.html#making_ripple_and_roll_edits)) refers to

> Edição de ondulação

which suggests

- *movimento de ondulação*

as possibly closer to being an established expression for "ripple move".

Comment: That word "edição" does establish and gives additional context to what is being done (the action) instead of us just calling it "movimento" which could mean other types of movements. Do you think "edição em ondulação" sounds too unnatural?

Comment: Frankly, both terms sound strange to me -- even in English I don't get why it's called the way it is and not, say, "group move" -- so I'm unsure which of them, "de" or "em", is best. As for the meaning of *edição* here, one [source](https://www.shutterstock.com/support/article/what-is-the-adobe-premiere-ripple-edit-tool) says "In Adobe Premiere, the ripple edit tool can be used to move an edit point and the entire sequence of clips that follow.", which sounds similar to Camtasia's "ripple move". Disclaimer:  I'm unfamiliar with both the software and this edition type.